# What are the earliest known origins of Sasquatches in Native American culture in the Americas?

Tags: folklore, native-american, cryptozoology, sasquatch

What are the earliest known origins of Sasquatches in Native American culture of North or South America?

Almost everybody has heard about these mysterious creatures known as [Sasquatches or Bigfoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigfoot), but can anyone tell me the earliest know legend (documented or otherwise) pertaining to this subject in Native American folklore?

[image: Life Size Image of a Bigfoot]